# google / cpc sessions show as (not set) / (not set) in Source / Medium report of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, pay-per-click

I started a new PPC campaign this month and all my google /cpc sessions are recorded as (not set) / (not set) in Source / Medium report.

[image]

When you click a ppc ad, you can see gclid in the address bar and in real time reporting it shows correctly as google / cpc.

But, under adwords tab in analytics account, it only shows the clicks and zero sessions.

[image]

2 accounts are linked correctly and auto-tagging is enabled in adwords.

Any help, idea or suggestion to investigate more regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious, if your issue has been resolved? We've had just the same experience, and we haven't been able to identify any root cause on our site, our campaign or analytics settings. Only one day's data was affected, and everything got back to normal.

Comment: nope, still no idea why this is happening and waiting for it to resolve itself :-/

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with the site. There was a plugging added to the site which converts all upper case letters into lower case in order to avoid duplicating the site URLs. For some SEO reason I guess. However, that converts Google Click ID (gclid) value (which contains both uppercase and lowercase letters) and that makes the gclid invalid.

This issue solved for me after getting this plug removed this.

Hope this will help someone.